# Cannot add New Team Project in VS2010. Error TF249063

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sharepoint, tfs

Good day,

I am trying to create a new team project from VS2010. We do currently have TFS projects on the server. However, once all the detail has been entered, I get the follwoing error message:

**TF218017: A SharePoint site could not be created for use as the team project portal. The following error occurred: TF249063: The following Web service is not available: http://{servername}/_vti_bin/TeamFoundationIntegrationService.asmx.**

1. The web service does not exist on the server.
2. According to this post: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tfssetup/archive/2010/10/04/tf249063-the-following-web-service-is-not-available.aspx I should run some commands using the stsadm.exe tool. However, the folder 'C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions' where the cmd tool is situated does not exist.

Can anyone shed some light on the situation at hand?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you check this post? http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/65f6433d-f663-4a8d-aa4c-5371a1ca9ddd/tf218017-a-sharepoint-site-could-not-be-created-for-use-as-the-team-project-portal-tf30063

Comment: @Blackstar: Checked it out, my problem is the web service does not even exist...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried skipping the creation of the sharepoint site when running through the wizard? It's not necessary to have the site running for the project to be added to TFS...

Comment: Will I lose out on features if I do it this way?

Comment: Apparently only really for knowledge-sharing purposes... You can read up about it over here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms253177(v=vs.100).aspx